# How to call method in ViewModel from another ViewModel?

Tags: android, mvvm

In my ViewModelOne I need to call a method from ViewModelTwo. How can I do that and is it a good practice?

Answer (score 1):

In clean code and MVVM structure(common way), Actually in a ViewModel, You don't have access to another ViewModel. You can use SharedViewModel to communicate via view(Fragment).

Comment: how to do this, please?